# WCF Server Side settings changeable by client app

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a WCF service that takes in files as reqeusts, processes the files, and returns responses asynchronously to the client. I want to add the ability to have a different client control the type and number of responses that are generated by the service.

For example, my service might return good responses, bad responses, and error responses. I want a UI client to be able to turn on/off each response type and change the number of good/bad responses that are returned.

This is my current service:

```
[ServiceContract(
SessionMode = SessionMode.Required,
CallbackContract = typeof(IEmulatorServiceCallback))]
public interface IEmulatorService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Submit(TransferredFile file);

    [OperationContract]
    bool Subscribe();

    [OperationContract]
    bool Unsubscribe();
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IEmulatorServiceCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void OnResponseReady(TransferredFile file);
}
```

On the client side, I have the following.

```
public interface IResponseListener : IEmulatorServiceCallback
{
    event EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> OnMessageReceived;
    bool Connect();
    void Disconnect();
}

[CallbackBehavior(
    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single,
    UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
[Export(typeof(IResponseListener))] // MEF
public class CallbackListener : IResponseListener
{
    // Sets up and creates the service to be used.
    public CallbackListener()
    {
        DuplexChannelFactory<IEmulatorService> pipeFactory =
              new DuplexChannelFactory<IEmulatorService>(
                  new InstanceContext(this),
                  new NetTcpBinding(),
                  new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:8000/EmulatorService"));

        _service = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
    }

    // Connects & Subscribes as service callback
    public bool Connect() { /* Code removed */ }

    // Removed as service callback
    public void Disconnect() { /* Code removed */ }

    // Implementation of interface that raises event to be captured by client   
    public void OnResponseReady(TransferredFile file) { /* Code removed */ }

    [Export]
    IEmulatorService _service;

    // Event raised when the OnResponseReady method is called
    public event EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> OnMessageReceived;
}

public interface IServiceProxy
{
    void SendMessage(string path);       
}

[Export(typeof(IServiceProxy))]
public class EmulatorServiceProxy : IServiceProxy
{
    public void SendMessage(string path)
    {
        var file = new TransferredFile(
            File.ReadAllBytes(path),
            Path.GetFileName(path));

        EmulatorService.Submit(file);
    }

    [Import]
    public IEmulatorService EmulatorService { get; set; }
}
```

Not to get too deep into the full implementation, but there is a bootstrapper for the client that gets the IResponseListener and IServiceProxy from MEF, then passes them into the ViewModel's constructor to be used there. So, the ViewModel, which is bound to a WPF app, actually uses the IServiceProxy and IResponseListener to update the model.

I expect that the client that uses the above service contract will most likely not be the same as the one that will control the settings (type/number of responses). I believe there will be one client that sets the settings at the user's request, and another client (part of a separate application) that will send requests and receive asynch responses.

So, I'm just not sure how to approach this. There are a couple of ways I'm considering:
1) Have a completely separate service that allows the client to change settings, and then somehow have the services share the settings contract.
2) Add a second Interface (for the settings) that this service implements and the settings contract will be within the service as well.

The first approach, I'm thinking it will be difficult to share these settings. However, I am using MEF, so it could be that this will make it easier.

As for the second approach, will that even work? Can I implement two service contracts with the same service class? If so, would I have to host the services separately?

I guess the other option is to just have all of the settings methods in the same service, but I wanted to separate them if possible so that when a client, who doesn't care about the settings, connects, they don't have to worry about those methods.

Has anyone had to do something similar? What approach would you recommend?

Thanks

-g